# ST_BUFFER in google bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis

To create a polygon around a pair of lat+lon coordinates I'd expect to be able to buffer the geogpoint:

e.g. `ST_BUFFER(ST_GEOGPOINT(lat, lon), 1000)`

This creates a circular polygon with a radius of 1000m.

Bigquery doesn't seem to have the buffer function, which seems like a really basic one - am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: See muscat's answer, but I also want to note that if you need ST_Buffer for distance query, like `ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(geo1, radius), geo2)`, you should instead use `ST_DWithin(geo1, geo2, radius)` in BigQuery - it should be faster and more precise.

Answer (score 3):

As for now, `ST_BUFFER` function is not supported in query engine yet. All available geography functions in Standard SQL you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions). Additionally, you can think about using buffer function from the open source library [Turf.JS](https://github.com/CartoDB/bigquery-jslibs/tree/master/sql/turf) to make buffers and use it in BigQuery:

```
jslibs.turf.ST_BUFFER(geometry_to_buffer GEOGRAPHY, radius NUMERIC, units STRING, steps NUMERIC)
```

Please follow [carto tutorial](https://carto.com/blog/spatial-functions-bigquery-uber/) to learn more about using this function.

Comment: All of the links to the CartoDB BiqQuery turfjs libs appear to be broken.

Comment: You can find them here https://docs.carto.com/spatial-extension-bq/sql-reference/transformations/#st_buffer

Answer (score 1):

ST_Buffer is now available (in preview)
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_buffer

There is also ST_BufferWithTolerance which allows one to specify approximation tolerance, rather than number of segments in polygon approximating the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, it's such an important geospatial function.

Comment: Hi Cristian, by Preview here I refer to the launch stage. See the note right below the function name in documentation.